# Push to datalayer not appearing in datalayer

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an events class,

```
/** Class representing a Google Analytics Event. */
class AnalyticsEventInterface {
  event = {};

  getEvent() {
    return this.event;
  }
}
```

and a specific event that extends the events class,

```
class SearchClickEvent extends AnalyticsEventInterface {
  /**
   * Create a SearchResultClick analytics event.
   * @param {string} term - The search result's landing query term.
   * @param {string} type - The type of search result's landing with.
   * @param {int} page - The page number of the result clicked.
   * @param {int} position - The calculated position of the result clicked.
   */
  constructor(term, type, page, position) {
    super();
    this.event.event = 'search_result_click';
    this.event.search_term = term;
    this.event.search_type = type;
    this.event.search_page = page;
    this.event.search_position = position;
  }
}
```

that is triggered when the click event occurs.

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.search_landing_page = function (context) {
    //When a search result is clicked a google analytics event is triggered and data collected.
    var logSearchClick = function (event) {
      var analyticsSettings = null;
      if (typeof Drupal !== "undefined" && typeof Drupal.settings !== "undefined" && typeof Drupal.settings.analytics !== "undefined") {
        analyticsSettings = Drupal.settings.analytics;
      }
      if (analyticsSettings === null) {
        // Escape early if we don't have the info that we need.
        return;
      }
      var queryTerm = analyticsSettings.term || null;
      var searchType = analyticsSettings.type || null;
      var pageNumber = analyticsSettings.page || null;
      var $results = $('.c-search-result');
      var resultsPerPage = $results.length;
      var positionData = $results.data('position');
      var positionID = positionData + ((pageNumber - 1) * resultsPerPage);
      var searchClickEvent = new SearchClickEvent(queryTerm, searchType, pageNumber, positionID);
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      window.dataLayer.push(searchClickEvent.getEvent())
    }

    // Attach the function to the event.
    $('.c-search-result').off('click').on('click', logSearchClick);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

From debugging, all the lines are being called and the event looks like it is being pushed but when I check the datalayer in the console after clicking the search result, the new event is not in the datalayer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I also don't have access to the client's GTM.

Comment: Can you share about the console for what the "searchClickEvent.getEvent()" function return?

Comment: searchClickEvent.getEvent(); I get Uncaught ReferenceError: searchClickEvent is not defined and dataLayer.push({'event': 'event'});  I get undefined but I can follow along with the code in the debugger